# Karma files: include everything, except ignore bower_components, except include specific bower files

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, bower

In a world where inclusions take precedence over exclusions this is what I want:

```
files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
],

exclude: [
  'app/bower_components/**/*.js'
],
```

However, in karma config, file exclusions take precedence.

Can I easily ignore whatever might be lurking in bower_components folder, except for the specific files I decide to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can do that with a pattern. Karma uses [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) internally, as such the following should work just fine for the case you present:

```
files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
],

exclude: [
  'app/bower_components/**/!(angular.js|angular-route|angular-mocks).js',
],
```

I just tried that out in our repo with a gazillion of `angular-` files, and even though it looks there is an extraneous `.js` in that pattern, it appears to be working.

> Exclude every `.js` file in *any* subfolder of `bower_components`, except for files named either `angular.js`, `angular-route` or `angular-mocks`.

Now, if you wanted to - you could replace the three topmost entries in your `files: []` array, and just put `app/bower_components/**/*.js` because as you said - *exclusion takes precedence here*. Just keep piling on filenames that you **dont** want to exclude and you should be automatically including those.

---

#### Edit

As pointed out by the OP - the negation in the exclude pattern need to be the full filenames including the extension, otherwise we run the risk of including folders matching said filename without an extension.

The new pattern would be:

```
'app/bower_components/**/!(angular.js|angular-route.js|angular-mocks.js).js',
```

> *Exclude all .js files from bower_components except angular.js, angular-route.js and angular-mocks.js*

---

As for inclusion, include `angular.js` before all others so as to not run the risk of angular dependent files being included first and crashing on itself.

Comment: Full praise because I now have a better understanding, but the answer is not quite correct:
1. The exclusion pattern should contain .js for each item, otherwise all .js files in e.g. the angular-route folder will load, and this will result in duplicate loads due to minification or pulling in other unwanted files. 
2. No matter what I try, replacing the three topmost entries with the `**/*.js` doesn't work for me - I get 'angular is not defined'.

NB: If you update your answer to reflect/confirm these findings I'll mark it as the answer :).

Comment: Hmm. The first point you are indeed correct, the !exclude entries need to be the full name of the file including its filetype. On point #2, I really don't know man. Can you try explicitly loading angular first, and then the rest?

Comment: Nice one! `files: ['app/bower_components/angular/angular.js', 'app/**/*.js']` and `exclude: '[app/bower_components/**/!(angular.js|angular-route.js|angular-mocks.js).js']` is the answer for me. NB: In case anyone else uses this, this is probably slower than just being explicit because the file search tree is larger.

Comment: Did you accept only to unaccept my answer right away? **What a tease, Dan!**

Comment: Haha, sorry, I was waiting for the bit about the inclusion to be added. I fully and wholeheartedly accept it now :)